# Command needed for proper textstyle

Tags: environments

I would like to know if there is a predefined latex command/environment/package that I can use to write something in style "Availability" or "Lecutures" shown in the picture below:

[image: ZPirmZVPEqfse4qKAmxMTjeP]

Comment: Look at enumitem package.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the `description` environment in combination with a custom `\item` command:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\newcommand\abbritem[2]{\item[{\normalfont #1 (\textbf{#2}):}]}

\begin{document}
\begin{description}
\abbritem{Availability}{A} \lipsum[1]
\abbritem{Lectures}{L} \lipsum[2]
\end{description}
\end{document}
```

[image]

---

If all your items follow the same `text (letter):` pattern, here's an alternative version with a more natural syntax that makes use of TeX's macro parameter pattern matching:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\def\abbritem#1(#2):{\item[{\normalfont #1 (\textbf{#2}):}]}

\begin{document}
\begin{description}
\abbritem Availability (A): \lipsum[1]
\abbritem Lectures (L): \lipsum[2]
\end{description}
\end{document}
```